# Can notification actions be handled while the device is locked?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, unusernotificationcenter, actionable-notification

I've been working with notifications for quite a while now, and I could've sworn that `userNotificationCenter(_:didReceive:withCompletionHandler:)` used to only be processed if the app was opened via the notification.

However, upon looking into [actionable notifications](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/declaring_your_actionable_notification_types), I found this:

> When the user selects an action, the system **launches your app in the background** and notifies the shared `UNUserNotificationCenter` object, which notifies its delegate. Use your delegate object's `userNotificationCenter(_:didReceive:withCompletionHandler:)` method to identify the selected action and provide an appropriate response.

Does this mean that the seemingly universal `didReceive` delegate method now works even while the device is locked?

Or must the app always be opened to actually do anything meaningful in response to notification actions (writing to local database, sending HTTPS requests, etc.)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the delegate works even if the device is locked. The app is only woken up if the user chose an action. Also, I am not sure how much time you will get before you invoke the completion block.

> Important
>
> If your response to action involves accessing files on disk,
>   consider a different approach. Users can respond to actions while the
>   device is locked, which would make files encrypted with the complete
>   option unavailable to your app. If that happens, you may need to save
>   changes temporarily and integrate them into your app's data structures
>   later.

Comment: That note confused me when I saw it. If you can't write to disk, what can you do? Is there a list somewhere of functionality that is, in fact, available when handling notification actions in the background?

Answer (score 0):

From this Delegate Method : `userNotificationCenter(_:didReceive:withCompletionHandler:)` notification is works when your device is locked, but if you want to perform any action.

For Example: Suppose through Notification you want to pick any phone call within application then you have to setup another things as well.
you have to set up PushKit Framework within your application . As shown in images: [image]

[image: You have to create the different cerificate as well for PushKit Framework]